# High School Chorus Sings on Airport Shuttle in Paris

Tags: choral-music

I was on YouTube watching random choir videos (since I’m a choir kid lol) and I came across this choir that was singing in a airport shuttle bus in Paris, I watched the video and it was absolutely beautiful!

But there’s a big problem, I don’t know the name of the song they sang! It’s not in English and I’ve been looking up everything but I can’t find it anywhere! Can anyone please help me? Here’s the link, https://youtu.be/gh1iv-tlMIM

I really want to show the song to my choir teacher so we can sing it at a concert but I need the name of it first. Thank you!

Comment: The video on YT states that the singers are "made up of students from Apex, Garner and Middle Creek". Middle Creek choirs have  a [Twitter account](https://twitter.com/mchschoirs?lang=en). You could ask the question there.  The piece sounds like it may be an arrangement of an African song, but what do I know....

Comment: @Angst ok thank you so much! I’ll try to do some research haha. And yea I thought it was either Swahili or Latin but I wasn’t sure. Thank you anyways for the info! Looks like I’ll have to tune in my inner detective lol.

Comment: it often happens that "name that song" questions are solved with good old-fashioned detecting around the non-musical aspects. Go for it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What a beautiful song!  This is called [Ukuthula](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yNqmpQPp-ns) and it's apparently a traditional Zulu hymn of peace.

I was able to recognize the characteristic call-and-response of South African choral music, and from there, I did my best to identify a searchable phoneme.

You'll find lyrics and a translation here:

https://kairossouthernafrica.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/a-south-african-chorus-ukuthula/

Comment: Thank you so much! I’ll show it to my choir teacher!

Comment: You're welcome, and thank you for introducing me to this lovely song. If this is the right answer, please mark it accepted using the checkmark next to the question.  It helps us keep our questions organized if we know which ones do and don't have accepted answers.

Comment: Interesting... _Ukuthala_ seems like a cognate of the hymn "Peace, Perfect Peace":  https://hymnary.org/text/peace_perfect_peace_in_this_dark_world_o . It's at least somewhat similar thematically, and very similar musically (identical chord progression).